# Why is an Ingress resource assigned external IPs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, ingress

I have a GKE cluster running with the `nginx-ingress` controller from the Kubernetes community (via Helm). I set it up with a regional IP which I had reserved in advance like so:

```
helm install stable/nginx-ingress \
  --set controller.service.loadBalancerIP=my.reserved.regional.ip
```

I then added a couple of Ingress resources with the `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"` annotation and nothing much else, and pointed them to a headless service in the cluster (a `type: ClusterIP`).

This works fine, and I can access the vhost-based ingresses via the load balancer IP.

However, I am wondering why the Ingress resources are also assigned an external IP:

```
==> v1beta1/Ingress
NAME           HOSTS                ADDRESS        PORTS  AGE
ingress-admin  admin.my-domain.com  35.195.255.71  80     24m
ingress-api    api.my-domain.com    35.195.255.71  80     24m
```

Is this normal? The IP responds to ping but does not serve HTTP (which my service does). Is there anything I need to do with the Ingress resources to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome @Achton on StackExchange.

To keep the same Reserved Static External IP Address in Ingress resources as assigned to Ingress Controller`s LB Service, you should set one more configuration parameter when installing nginx-ingress controller with helm chart, this is:

```
--set controller.publishService.enabled=true
```

as explained in NGINX Ingress Controller documentation [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/static-ip/)

Comment: Thanks Nepomucen - is my service required to be of type LoadBalancer? Because I'm currently using only "headless" services (with "clusterIP: none").

Comment: It should be of ClusterIP Type, if you want to expose services externally via Ingress Controller, backed with the same static LoadBalancer`s IP address.